# how to get part of an error message from a responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, error-handling

I have an error function that i am trying to display only part of the message
as follows:

```
function onError(result) {
                           // alert(result.responseText);
                            var message = JSON.parse(result.responseText).more_info;
                            $('<div>' + message + '</div>').dialog({
                                modal: true,
                                resizable: false,
                                title: "Test",
                                buttons: { "Okay": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
                            });
                        }
```

however the above message comes back as undefined.
This is how my result comes back

```
{\"more_info\":\"method should have required property\",\"category\":\"api_request_error\",\"description\":\"One or more request parameters are invalid.\"}"
```

i only want to display in my message the "more_info" string. so my message should only show "method should have required property"

how can i achieve this?

Comment: There is no `message` property in the JSON you've shown. Use either `more_info`, `category` or `description`

Comment: try `JSON.parse(result.responseText).more_info;`. That json has no 'message' propery.

Comment: sorry i didnt update it, i already tried more_info and it comes back with same undefined

Comment: _“This is how my result comes back”_ - then the JSON parser probably simply refuses to parse it, because of all those backslashes in front of the double quotes …

Comment: @04FS so how would i achieve this

Comment: Well you would start by making the endpoint you are requesting this data from, return _actual_ JSON, and not something that looks a bit like JSON, but ins’t actually.